# How to add data (or single point) to an existing 3d scatter plotly exprees plot in python

Tags: python, plotly, scatter3d

I have a code that makes a plot similar to this one:

```py
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go
df = px.data.tips()
fig = go.Figure(data =[go.Scatter3d(x = df['total_bill'],
                                   y = df['time'],
                                   z = df['tip'],
                                   mode ='markers')])
fig.show()
```

I want to add a single point with different symbol and see it among the rest of the points

I have tried this

```py
fig.add_trace(
    go.scatter3d(x=[25],
                 y=['Dinner'],
                 z=[6],
                 mode='markers')
)
```

and gave me:
`TypeError: 'module' object is not callable`

Can it be done?
This is what I am looking for:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8RIfk.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem it's a typo in your code. You used `go.scatter3d` instead of `go.Scatter3d`

```
fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter3d(x=[25],
                 y=['Dinner'],
                 z=[6],
                 mode='markers')
)
```

Comment: Great, 9 hours of coding and the eyes seem to fail to distinguish a capital S from a small one... what a shame... Thanks!!!

Comment: Don't worry. It happens to everyone.