# How to highlight xyz points in plotly 3d mesh?

Tags: python, plotly, mesh

I have created a mesh 3d figure in plotly

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure(data=[
    go.Mesh3d(
        x=[0, 1, 0, 0],
        y=[0, 0, 1, 0],
        z=[0, 0, 0, 1],
        i=[0, 0, 0, 1],
        j=[1, 2, 3, 2],
        k=[2, 3, 1, 3],
    )
])

fig.show()
```

[image]

How can I highlight the xyz-points? So that it looks like the following:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I referred to [@rpanai's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69474843/7789963) from [How to add data (or single point) to an existing 3d scatter plotly exprees plot in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69473936/how-to-add-data-or-single-point-to-an-existing-3d-scatter-plotly-exprees-plot/69474843#69474843).

---

You can use the following code before `fig.show()` to get x-y-z points:

```
fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter3d(x=[0, 1, 0, 0],
                 y=[0, 0, 1, 0],
                 z=[0, 0, 0, 1],
                 mode='markers')
)
```